# SQL Convert STRING to INT with NULL on invalid value

Tags: sql, mariadb

As the title say, I'm trying to convert a STRING to an INT but i need a NULL value when the string is invalid.

I've already tried with CAST and CONVERT

```
SELECT CONVERT("TEST", INT) FROM DUAL
SELECT CAST("TEST" AS INT) FROM DUAL
```

but both the functions returns 0 for invalid value.

There is a short way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the value is looks like a valid integer:

```
select (case when col regexp '^[0-9]{1,10}$'
             then cast(col as unsigned)
        end)
```

Or, you could just use implicit conversion:

```
select nullif(col + 0, 0)
```

However, this converts zeros to `NULL`.